# CSS Background has a effect, how can i turn it off?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on the following site
http://photographymert.com/about/

Active page link turns to blue, but it must appear with a white background but it has a some box effect that i couldn't turn it off, having going through developer tools again and again.

What am I missing? How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `bootstrap.css` (line 4632), a `box-shadow` is applied on

```
.navbar .nav > .active > a,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:focus
```

Best practice is not to alter the Bootstrap CSS, so you can override this by setting `box-shadow: none` on the `a` element.

Comment: If you try this in chrome dev tools it doesn't work, also that LI not showing a box shadow.   However, on the A element it works great.  Good show.

Comment: thank you for your help! it worked flawlessly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Bootstrap CSS inherting your Ul li a >

You can modify from : 
.navbar .nav > .active > a, .navbar .nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar .nav > .active > a:focus ( Bootstrap.css  line number : 4632 ) and remove box shadow.